# How to test multiple console outputs with Jest in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, junit, jestjs, babel-jest

I need this solution for an educational project. This unit test should check an expected console output from the function:

```
it('should log into the console "Victoria lifting anchor up" and "Victoria is moving"', () => {

  const consoleSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');

  victoria.move();

  expect(consoleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(?);

});
```

The problem is that the function victoria.move() runs two console logs, and I want to check both of them in one unit test. The test perfectly works with one output, but I do not know what notation should be for testing two outputs. I strugle to find the syntax on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.calls` property of `consoleSpy`. There is an example in the official documentation ["using a mock function"](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions). In your case it could be done like this

```js
expect(mockCallback.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('your value'); // first call, first argument
expect(mockCallback.mock.calls[1][0]).toBe('your value');  // second call, first argument
```